# Mongodb skip and limit not working properly for pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a project where huge amount of data (in lacks) being stored in the mongodb collection using mongoose. So instead of using `mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2`, I'm using `skip` and `limit` for pagination.

But the pagination is not working properly. The data shown in the first page is also being shown in the second page. I think as name suggests `skip` just skipping the number of records and showing the remaining records in the response.

This is the query I'm using

```
assets.aggregate(
  [
    { $skip: 1 },
    { $match: { company: "61bf118b87b32c3ccc7a96a6" } },
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    { $limit: 10 },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "tickets",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "assets",
        as: "ticket_assets",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "locations",
        localField: "location",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "locationData",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$locationData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "stores",
        localField: "sublocation",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "sublocation",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$sublocation", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "user_dropdowns",
        localField: "category",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "categoryData",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$categoryData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "user_dropdowns",
        localField: "type",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "typeData",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$typeData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "admin_dropdowns",
        localField: "asset_status",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "assetStatusData",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$assetStatusData", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "user_dropdowns",
        localField: "condition",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "assetCondition",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$assetCondition", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "stores",
        localField: "deployedAt",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "deployedStore",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$deployedStore", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "company_contacts",
        localField: "assignedObj.allottedTo",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "assignedEmployee",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: { path: "$assignedEmployee", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "locations",
        localField: "using_location",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "assetUsingLocation",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path: "$assetUsingLocation",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        asset_name: 1,
        asset_code: 1,
        status: 1,
        createdAt: 1,
        assetId: 1,
        location: { $ifNull: ["$locationData", null] },
        sublocation: { $ifNull: ["$sublocation", null] },
        category: { $ifNull: ["$categoryData", null] },
        type: { $ifNull: ["$typeData", null] },
        asset_status: { $ifNull: ["$assetStatusData", null] },
        ticketCount: { $size: "$ticket_assets" },
        deployedAt: { $ifNull: ["$deployedStore", null] },
        assignedTo: {
          $ifNull: [
            {
              fullName: "$assignedEmployee.fullName",
              _id: "$assignedEmployee._id",
            },
            null,
          ],
        },
        condition: { $ifNull: ["$assetCondition", null] },
        using_location: { $ifNull: ["$assetUsingLocation", null] },
        predictive_maintenance: 1,
        maintenanceValidationData: 1,
        allocationValidationData: 1,
        purchasedFrom: 1,
        warrantyDue: 1,
        lifeTime: 1,
        purchaseDate: 1,
        asset_price: 1,
      },
    },
  ]
);
```

And please find the attached images of how the response being shown in the frontend table.
[image]
[image]

Is there any other alternative to fix the pagination in my code or where I'm making the mistake to get the correct pagination.

Comment: You need to move the $skip part to next of $match and $sort sections in aggregation query. [$match,$sort,$skip,$limit,...others]

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed, `$skip` skips X documents. It has no way to know how you manage your pages in the front-end, it might be pages of 5/10/25/50 documents.

In the request you make to your API, pass it as parameters something like this: `/my/awesome/route/results?page_number=5&page_size=10`.

That way, in your endpoint via `req.params`, you know that you have to `$skip` 4 pages times 10 results, so `$skip: 40`.

---

An example for this would be:

Say your URL is: `https://my-api.com/data-to-retrieve?page_number=3,page_size=10`.

You would do

```
const myApiRoute = (req, res, next) => {
  // -1 because if you want page two, you want the results from 11 to 20, and not from 21 to 30
  const pageSize = parseInt(req.query.page_size) - 1;
  const pageNumber = parseInt(req.query.page_number);
  assets.aggregate(
  [
    { $skip: pageSize * pageNumber },
    { $match: { company: "61bf118b87b32c3ccc7a96a6" } },
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
    { $limit: pageSize },
    { [...]
}
```

Comment: I'm using like this, ```{ $skip: parseInt(req.query.page) }, { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },{ $limit: parseInt(req.query.pageSize) },``` but I don't know where am making mistakes

Comment: For example, I want to go to 2nd page and I want to see 11th to 20th records.

Comment: I'm using the page and pageSize as mentioned above, @Gaëtan Boyals , is it right or should I make any changes to that

Comment: Thanks @Gaëtan Boyals. But still two to three records of previous page coming in next page too. But will try to work on them

Comment: Glad I could help! Yeah you might have to tweak `$skip` and `$limit` parameters by adding or substracting "1" here and there but you get the general idea.